# Webpack TypeScript and xgettext translations

Tags: django, webpack, django-i18n, xgettext

I have a Django app and am using Django's i18n module to help translating my strings. For translating JavaScript, I run

```
python manage.py makemessages -d djangojs
```

which adds all marked strings to a .po file. This works quite well for all my boring .js files in my static folder. However, we are starting to use webpack to pack some typescript (.tsx files) into a bundle.js file. This file is copied to the static folder after building, so I expected Djangos `makemessages` to pick up the strings from it as well. However, it seems that the strings are not parsed correctly, because most of the code in bundle.js is simply strings wrapped in `eval()`.

I believe this means that I need webpack to - in addition to the bundle.js file - create a .js file for each .tsx file without all of the `eval()` nonsense, so that django's `makemessages` can parse it properly. I have no idea how to do this, however. My current config looks like this

```
var path = require("path");
var WebpackShellPlugin = require('webpack-shell-plugin');

var config = {
    entry: ["./src/App.tsx"],

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },

    devtool: 'source-map',

    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: "ts-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
            test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
                }, {
                    loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
                }, {
                    loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new WebpackShellPlugin({
            onBuildEnd:['./cp_to_static.sh'],
            dev: false  // Needed to trigger on npm run watch
        })
    ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

- So how can I make webpack spit out these files?
- Is this the right thing to do, or is there a way to make Django parse bundle.js properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that all of the eval nonsense was generated by webpacks "watch" function. When simply running webpack for building the script, it works as expected